# Generate random geo-coordinate based on distance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, math, coordinates, core-location

I want to create a method that returns a random `CLLocationCoordinate2D` (or `CLLocation` object) based on another `CLLocationCoordinate2D` (or `CLLocation`). The generated coordinate should be within a certain distance (**not** degree, so based on a `CLLocationDistance` value or equivalent, **not** `CLLocationDegrees`) of the base coordinate in any random direction. So I'm basically generating a random coordinate within a circular boundary.

I understand how to do this easily in a regular coordinate system (just use some basic trig to calculate a new coordinate from a random angle and radius from the center of the boundary), however I'm stuck on how to do it in a latitude/longitude system. I could easily do this using trig if I wanted to generate a random coordinate based on degree differences, but those results would get skewed the closer I get to a pole, so I want to do it based on distance.

I couldn't find anything in the documentation that might be able to help me. If there were some way to get a new coordinate by displacing an existing coordinate based on some direction and distance, that would certainly be helpful, but I haven't found anything for that in documentation or on the web. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula). The short version of that is: the distances are dependent on the longitudes of the start and end points and the best/fast way to calculate this is using a formula know as the Haversive formula. There is also an [Objective C implementation here](http://www.jaimerios.com/?p=39).